# Behaviour kidnapping mouse and keys

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker

I am having a problem with `DateTimePicker` when I show the `UpDown` arrows. It actually happens also with the `numericUpDown` control. It does not happen with the calendar.

If I click with the mouse in any field of the `DateTimePicker` and then click the arrows to change the value, I cannot then leave the control.

Sorry, I don't really know how to explain this properly (probably the reason why I haven't found anything about this when searching). The software does not hang but nothing works apart from the `DateTimePicker;` for instance, I can click with the mouse in a button and the visual effects will run but not the click event...

So, the only I can do is to force the program to close. It is like if it was just stealing the focus or the mouse click event and the keys events and not letting it go anywhere else. The tab key doesn't work either.

The `dateTimepicker` is bonded to a column in a `datatable` and there is not code into them at all.

I am sure this is something stupid that I am missing, but I am getting already frustrated with it.
Any advise please?

Comment: in what programming language?

Comment: I am working with managed c++ but I have reproduced it also in c#. It is .Net 3.5

Comment: This is undiagnosable from the description.  You'll need to post a small repro project that exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that this only happens when the property Text of the controls with UPDown (DateTimePicker and NumericUpDown) is binded. It does not do it when the property Value is binded instead.

Although this solves the problem in my applycation, the behaviour is there and cannot find an explanation for it.